# Java Creating an Instance of a Object

Tags: java, database, class, instance

I am trying to create 2 classes.

The first is called cellar with this I haven't had any problems:

```
class Cellar{   
    private String Name_Cellar;
    private String D_O;

    public String toString(){String values= Name_Cellar +" "+ D_O;return values;}

    public Cellar(String NameCellar, String DO) {
        this.Name_Cellar= NameCellar;
        this.D_O= DO;
    }
    public void setName(String NameCellar) {this.Name_Cellar= NameCellar;}
    public String getName() {return Name_Cellar;}

    public void setDO (String DO) {this.D_O = DO;}
    public String getDO() {return D_O;}
}
```

The problem begins in the second class:

```
class Wines{

    private String Name_Wine;
    private Cellar Fabricant;
    private String Type;
    private float Grad_Alch;
    private int Date;
}
```

Fabricant must be an instance of object type Cellar.

How could i do it?

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: ...what do you mean?
`private Cellar Fabricant = new Cellar();`

Comment: In class Wines, Fabricant have to be an Instance of Cellar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you've done it correctly in your code.

```
private Cellar Fabricant;//Definition
//...
Fabricant = new Cellar(NameCellar, DO);//Initialization
```

for example:

```
private Cellar Fabricant;//Definition
//...
String NameCellar = "what you want", Do = "whatever";
Fabricant = new Cellar(NameCellar, DO);//Initialization
```

Comment: I have a question Mok, why when I put  Fabricant = new Cellar(NameCellar, DO);  Tells me that NameCellar, can't be resolved to variable?

Comment: @devtreat> Oh, yes. You should define and initialize them first. I improve my answer with an example now.